# Reverse table td with jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to flip/reverse `td` values of a table.

If I fx: put a class on the td section I want flipped and name it 'valuesToFlip'

```
$('.valuesToFlip').reverse() // not working.
```

Comment: What do you mean by reverse? Change text from `this` to `siht`? Or reverse the order of the `td` cells in the row? Or reverse the order of `td` in the entire table...?

Comment: reverse the ordering of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

**[`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)** can be used with array, to convert it to array use **[`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)** and apply **[`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)**. Now for updating the order append back them using **[`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)**

```js
var $td = $('.valuesToFlip');
$td.parent().append($td.get().reverse());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="valuesToFlip">1
    </td>
    <td class="valuesToFlip">2
    </td>
    <td class="valuesToFlip">3
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```